# Is there any way to rectify stringApp communication error despite newer versions of STRING App and Cytoscape installed?

Tags: string, cytoscape, ppi, general-network-error

I am working on Cytoscape 3.9.1 and have stringApp 2.0.0 installed in my system.
Today, I tried importing 72 genes to String (both by web and in Cytoscape software).

STRING App web says `stringApp communication error. Confirm that you have installed the latest version of stringApp (1.6+) and Cytoscape (3.8+).`

I am getting an error message in Cytoscape: "This action cannot be performed on the current network as it appears to be an Old STRING network. Would you like to get the latest STRING network for the nodes in your network?

I have three options to solve
OK, upon clicking this, another dialogue box opens to Re-query the network.
Cancel, upon clicking this, the dialogue box closes.
Close the dialogue box, upon clicking this dialogue box closes.

My Cytoscape task history shows like this

```
  Loading data from STRING for 72 identifier(s).
 Network error: Unexpected error from server: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: https://api11.jensenlab.org/network
 
 POSTing JSON from https://api11.jensenlab.org/network
 Unexpected error from server: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: https://api11.jensenlab.org/network

  Re-query network
 null
 
 Caught exception executing task.
```

Can someone help me how to solve this problem?

I tried to generate PPI using STRING App and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The backend database was having problems yesterday.  It should be fixed now -- can you try again?